# CMake : Changing name of Visual Studio and Xcode exectuables depending on configuration in a project generated by CMake

Tags: cmake

What I need to do is to setup my excecutable name to be

```
program-debug for debug builds and 
program-release(or whatever) for other builds
```

I want to do it in a true cross-platform way and what is also very important - I want to target XCode and VS2008 - so when I change configuration in a kind of drop-down list, it must also have correct names for output! I do no want to regenerate .vcproj or .xcodeproj with other -D option (but I will have to if will not found a solution)

AFAIK cmake variable CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE should work for make-based generators - in is evaluated **at make time** (Correct me if I am wrong)

Basically it is how to setup target options (not nessesary name) depending on configuration in some IDEs/build system. It can be too specific for overall cmake goals, but maybe you can help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the list of [target properties](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#section_PropertiesonTargets): One of those is the [OUTPUT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:OUTPUT_NAME) and [OUTPUT_NAME_<CONFIG>](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:OUTPUT_NAME_CONFIG). The last one can be set for each config-type (Debug, Release, MinSizeRel, etc.) You can set them on your program with [set_target_properties](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:set_target_properties), e.g.:

```
project( YourProject )

add_executable( myprogram ${YourSources} )
set_target_properties( myprogram PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME_DEBUG program-debug )
set_target_properties( myprogram PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME_RELEASE program-release )
```

Take care that you need to set [RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME_<CONFIG>](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME_CONFIG) and/or [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME_<CONFIG>](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME_CONFIG) as well in some cases.