# How to not add Release or Debug to output path?

Tags: cmake

Here is my current settings for output :

```
set( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
set( LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
set( RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
```

But for some reason I do not want (MSVS) put out files to bin/Release or Debug folders in my bin folder. Can I realize it using CMake somehow?

*thank you*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747857/in-cmake-how-do-i-work-around-the-debug-and-release-directories-visual-studio-2) was asked a few months ago, where I advised the use of [target properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#section_PropertiesonTargets) and also referred to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561754/cmake-changing-name-of-visual-studio-and-xcode-exectuables-depending-on-config). For MSVC you can completely specify the locations of executables, libraries, archives, etc. on a per-configuration basis.

E.g. using something like:

```
if ( MSVC )
    set_target_properties( ${targetname} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${youroutputdirectory} )
    set_target_properties( ${targetname} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${youroutputdirectory} )
    set_target_properties( ${targetname} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${youroutputdirectory} )
    # etc for the other available configuration types (MinSizeRel, RelWithDebInfo)
endif ( MSVC )
```

which will put all your libraries in a single output-directory ${youroutputdirectory}, whether it is in Debug or Release config.

Comment: Your version works very well for me, while the linked answer with the added CMAKE_ does not work. (LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY works though). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: For me, the problem of target properties seems to be that I have to add all those lines for each and every subproject, haven't I?

Answer (score -1):

use `cmake -G 'Ninja'` in msvc 2015+