# How to change the executable output directory for Win32 builds, in CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

My problem is as such :
I'm developing a small parser using Visual Studio 2010.
I use CMake as a build configuration tool.

But I find the default executable building behaviour, inconvenient.
What I want is, have my final program be located in :

```
E:/parsec/bin/<exe-name>.<build-type>.exe
```

rather than

```
E:/parsec/bin/<build-type>/<exe-name>.exe
```

How would you do that using CMake ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Copy the executable after building
2. Customizing the output-directory for your executable(s)

### Copy the executable after building

After a succesful build you can copy the executable (see Beginners answer), but perhaps it is nicer to use an install target:

Use the [install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:install) command to specify targets (executables, libraries, headers, etc.) which will be copied to the [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX) directory. You can specify the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX on the commandline of cmake (or in the cmake GUI).

### Customizing the output-directory for your executable(s)

**Warning:** It is not advised to set absolute paths directly in your cmakelists.txt.

Use [set_target_properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:set_target_properties) to customize the [RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)

```
set_target_properties( yourexe PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY E:/parsec/bin/ )
```

As an alternative, modifying the [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) allows you to specify this for **all** targets in the cmake project. Take care that you modify the [CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) as well when you build dlls.

```
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib )
```

**Additional info**: Take a look at these questions:

- [In CMake, how do I work around the Debug and Release directories Visual Studio 2010 tries to add?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747857/in-cmake-how-do-i-work-around-the-debug-and-release-directories-visual-studio-2)
- [CMake : Changing name of Visual Studio and Xcode exectuables depending on configuration in a project generated by CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561754/cmake-changing-name-of-visual-studio-and-xcode-exectuables-depending-on-config)
- [How to not add Release or Debug to output path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848268/how-to-not-add-release-or-debug-to-output-path)

Comment: `set_target_properties` is certainly the way to go; set_properties can too easily be overwritten by another included  project in the cache.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you will need to copy your binaries with a separate custom command which would look similar to this one:

```
add_custom_command(target your_target_name
          POST_BUILD
          COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${EXAMPLE_BIN_NAME} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/.
)
```