# Set cmake target name for debug and release configuration

Tags: debugging, configuration, cmake, release

I am trying to differentiate between a debug and release build.

If a **debug** build is in progress I want to install myLib**d** in /usr/local/lib. 
If a **release** build is in progress I want to install myLib in /usr/local/lib.

Here is my approach

```
IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES RELEASE)
    SET(LIB_NAME myLib) 
ELSE()
    SET(LIB_NAME myLibd) 
ENDIF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES RELEASE)

ADD_LIBRARY(${LIB_NAME} ${Source_files} ${Header_files})
INSTALL(TARGETS ${LIB_NAME} DESTINATION /usr/local/lib)
```

However, the target name is in both cases (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug or Release) always myLib**d**. What is the problem here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMake : Changing name of Visual Studio and Xcode exectuables depending on configuration in a project generated by CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561754/cmake-changing-name-of-visual-studio-and-xcode-exectuables-depending-on-config)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Solution

Set [CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CONFIG_POSTFIX.html) variable:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX)
  set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
endif()
```

#### Details

> What is the problem here?

- You need to use `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)` instead of `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES RELEASE)`
- Probably you need to clean build directory
- Note that `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE...)` approach will not work for [multi-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt/24470998#24470998) generators

Comment: btw, when linking debug/release configuration, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209929/linking-different-libraries-for-debug-and-release-builds-in-cmake-on-windows) helps

Answer (score 2):

```
set_property(TARGET ${LIB_NAME} PROPERTY DBG_POSTFIX d)
```

**Reference**

- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/CONFIG_POSTFIX.html?highlight=postfix

Comment: It's `DEBUG_POSTFIX`, because the name of `<CONFIG>` in the variable definition is `Debug` then capitalized for variable name purposes.